# How Should I Define an Array of Pointers to Functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to make an array of functions so I can call functions from the array with an index. I can't seem to figure out the parentheses, asterisks and brackets to create this array of functions. Here is what I have:

```
void Game::getPawnMoves(int position, bool color, Move ** moveList) {
    ...
}

typedef void (*GetMoveFunction) (int, bool, Move **);
void Game::getLegalMoves(Move ** moveList) {
    GetMoveFunction functions[] = 
    {
        getPawnMoves, 
        getKnightMoves, 
        getBishopMoves,
        getRookMoves,
        getQueenMoves,
        getKingMoves
    };
    ...
}
```

All of the getPawnMoves, getKnightMoves, and the rest all have the same arguments and all return void. Move is just a struct with two chars and an enum. In this case, if you'd like to try compiling it, you could replace Move ** with int **.

The error I'm getting when I compile is:

```
Game.cpp:443:5: error: cannot convert ‘Game::getPawnMoves’ from type 
‘void (Game::)(int, bool, Move**) {aka void (Game::)(int, bool, Move_t**)}’ to 
type ‘GetMoveFunction {aka void (*)(int, bool, Move_t**)}’
```

So for some reason the compiler thinks that GetMoveFunction is void * instead of void, but if I change the typedef to

```
typedef void (GetMoveFunction) (int, bool, Move **);
```

I get the error:

```
Game.cpp:435:28: error: declaration of ‘functions’ as array of functions
  GetMoveFunction functions[] =
```

I'm honestly super stuck on this one. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Regular function pointers can't point to non-static member functions. There are *member* function pointers that can do that.

Comment: `std::vector<std::function<void(int, bool, Move**)>>`? Then use lambdas or `std::bind` or similar tools to use specific objects.

Comment: `void (*)(int, bool, Move_t**)` is the same type `GetMoveFunction` refers to. You could write (for imho improved readability): `using GetMoveFunction = void (*)(int, bool, Move_t**);` instead of the typedef and it would mean the exact same thing. The type has nothing to do with `void*`; the brackets around `*` change the meaning.

Comment: The first error, the code you didn't show as part of a proper [mcve] would  reveal that `Game::getPawnMoves` is a non-static member function. Therefore, the actual type of that function is `void (Game::*)(int, bool, Move **)`, not  `void (*)(int, bool, Move **)`. The second error is just a side-show of misunderstanding the first error and stabbing at a solution.

Comment: Member functions, unless declared `static` are not normal functions because they have an hidden argument `this` that refers to the instanced object.

Comment: I suspect in the not-too-distant future we'll be fielding a question about how the [member access operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) work with this, specifically the pointer-to-member access operators, now that there is a table of member functions rather than a table of functions. [See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/KhsjTbxYz).

Comment: @MatG No, that's not the reason.  You still need an instance of the class to call them.

Comment: Note: Don't update the question to include the answer. Questions should remain questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How Should I Define an Array of Pointers to Functions in C++?

> ```
> typedef void (*GetMoveFunction) (int, bool, Move **);
> ```

This is a pointer to function.

> ```
> GetMoveFunction functions[] = 
> {
>     // ...
> };
> ```

This is an array of pointers to functions. You've achieved what you asked for in the title of the question.

---

> ```
> Game.cpp:443:5: error: cannot convert ‘Game::getPawnMoves’ from type 
> ‘void (Game::)(int, bool, Move**) {aka void (Game::)(int, bool, Move_t**)}’ to 
> type ‘GetMoveFunction {aka void (*)(int, bool, Move_t**)}’
> ```

The problem here is that you are trying to initialise the function pointers using non-static member functions. Function pointers cannot point to non-static member functions.

What you probably need is an array of pointers to **member** functions of `Game` instead. Another option is an array of type erasing function wrappers (`std::function`).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll edit my question with the updated code.